# Some packages have only italic font

Tags: fonts, gui

Hello I am running ubuntu 18.04 with gnome. 
Some packages (like zenmap and audacous) have italic fonts even though I have my font in gnome tweak set to Ubuntu light and medium.

Comment: Is your system using English or some other language?

Comment: Yup I am using english and i have narrowed it down to gtk+.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have figured it out. The theme of my problems are almost always configs so i tried removing them that fixed the issue by creating a new config file.